# How to re-use the rigging animation in unity 2d for right and left movement?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

I'm playing around with the rigging in Unity 2D and I was wondering is there a way to apply the bones from a sprite facing right and flip them to apply them to a left sprite and do the same for the animation? I tried to just flip the player, but it breaks the bone depth...

I would like to know **how to avoid the animation being different when moving from right to left with 2D rigging**? There must be a way to do it, they just don't show it in the documentation / tutorials.

Comment: how are you flipping the sprite, because I would have thought it would turn with it

Comment: You're right, but even if it works, I want to make my character custom when he looks to the right or the left, it has 2 different sprites, some accessories, or tattoos are not visible depending which side he's facing

Comment: Yeah but the bone rigging is custom to the sprite???